# Unable to handle alerts in selenium webdriver on firefox using java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, firefox, alerts

When i login to my web, a pop up alert occurs "Would you allow MyWeb to send you notifications" but as it has no HTML I can not find its locators.

```
try {
        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
        Alert alert=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        presentFlag=true;
        alert.accept();
    }
catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a JS alert? It doesn't sound like it would be one given the description. What happens when you run your code? What is the error? You should edit your question and post the full error message there.

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate your webdriver tyr doing this:

```
FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
ffProfile.setPreference("permissions.default.desktop-notification", 1);
FirefoxOptions ffOpts = new FirefoxOptions();
ffOpts.setProfile(ffProfile);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffOpts);
```

Comment: Alexey , when i tried to use solution mentioned by you , my browser got stuck and URL is not accessible , i used this code in my setBrowserConfig() method.

Comment: Can you show your `setBrowserConfig()` method code?

Comment: `public static void setBrowserConfig() { System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\geckodriver.exe"); //try to handle pop up FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile(); ffProfile.setPreference("permissions.default.desktop-notification", 1); FirefoxOptions ffOpts = new FirefoxOptions(); ffOpts.setProfile(ffProfile); WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffOpts); //driver=new FirefoxDriver(); }`

Comment: Instead of `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffOpts); //driver=new FirefoxDriver();` you should use `driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffOpts);` otherwise you change the webdriver that is only locally visible in your method.

Comment: **Alexey** i changed WebDriver to driver and  i added the following preference , now its working fine.         ` ffOpts.addPreference("media.navigator.permission.disabled", true);`    Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below function,

Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

alert.accept();

Comment: What you have suggested is the same as what Saman already has. `EC.alertIsPresent()` returns the `Alert` which is stored in `alert` and then is accepted.

Comment: Hi Jeffc,   correct me if i am wrong ..as per my above comment driver will move the focus to popup so i dont think what saman suggested and my comment are same.

Comment: The `wait.until(EC.alertIsPresent())` also switches context to the alert before accepting so the two are equivalent. I just tried it to confirm.

Comment: Cool...Thanks  @JeffC